# Check if string variations are within a string

Tags: python, string

I should note that we are only allowed to use built in python string functions and loop functions.

A = 'bet[bge]geee[tb]bb'

B = 'betggeeetbb'

The square brackets mean any single one of the characters inside the bracket can be used so you could have

1. bet`b`geee`t`bb
2. bet`g`geee`t`bb
3. bet`e`geee`t`bb
4. bet`b`geee`b`bb
5. bet`g`geee`b`bb
6. bet`e`geee`b`bb

How do I check A will have a combination that can be found within B.
A can have any number of brackets, with a minimum of 2 characters and a maximum of 4 characters in each square bracket

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this problem yourself? Please show it

Comment: So, you're looking for regex then

Comment: @everyone suggesting regex: Regex has a lot more features than just "things in square brackets". Correctly escaping all the regex metacharacters _except_ the character classes is probably more difficult than writing a non-regex solution.

Comment: @roganjosh I can't wrap my head around how to do so when you consider there could be any number of brackets. I can split the string and check for the text before the bracket, then check for any possibility in the brackets, then check the text after the bracket. But I am unsure of how to loop it to cover n loops

Comment: How would you do it without a computer? Work that out, turn it into a step-by-step procedure, and translate that into working code.

Comment: @user2372210 can `A` or `B` contain some chars except `a-z`?

Comment: @TomZych I'll try it out. I can plot it out on paper, but again I can't consider any number of brackets

Comment: @Pavel It could also be a wildcard (* valid for any char), but for now lets assume a-z so I can understand it

Comment: Okay, a hint: do things one way for letters outside brackets; do things another way for letters inside brackets.

Comment: @user2372210 so you can't use regex?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the [regular expressions library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). The solution is literally the `re.match` function, whose documentation includes the following bit:

> `[]` Used to indicate a set of characters. In a set:
>
> - Characters can be listed individually, e.g. [amk] will match 'a', 'm', or 'k'.

Since regular expressions use backslashes for their own purpose (beyond Python's normal escapes, e.g. `"\n"` to represent a newline), [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) are idiomatic in the matching string.

```
>>> import re
>>> A = r'bet[bge]geee[tb]bb'
>>> B = 'betggeeetbb'
>>> m = re.match(A, B)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 11), match='betggeeetbb'>
>>> m.group(0)
'betggeeetbb'
```

You can also verify that it doesn't match if (say) the second bracket is not matched:

```
>>> C = "betggeeezbb"
>>> m = re.match(A, C)
>>> m is None
True
```

Before you go about adding this liberally to an existing project, make sure you understand:

- What is the difference between [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)?
- What is the cost of creating a regular expression? [How can you avoid](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) this cost if the regular expression is used repeatedly?
- How can you [extract parts of a matching expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) (e.g. the character matched by `[bge]` in your example)?
- How can you perform [matches on strings that contain newlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M)?

Finally, when learning regular expressions (similarly to learning class inheritance), it's tempting to use them everywhere. Meditate on [this koan from Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.

Comment: _"The solution is literally the re.match function"_ It's not. You have to use `re.fullmatch`, or add an end-of-string anchor `$` to the regex. Also, please don't use the term "raw string"; it gives newbies the impression that they're some kind of special string. Please call them "raw string literals" instead.

Comment: The question asked if the string variation was within another string. `fullmatch` isn't quite it, and maybe even my suggestion of `match` was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to break your problem up into simpler tasks. There are many ways to convert your pattern from just a plain string into something with more structure, but here's something that uses only plain string operations to get you started:

```
def parse_pattern(pattern):
    '''
    >>> parse_pattern('bet[bge]geee[tb]bb')
    ['b', 'e', 't', ['b', 'g', 'e'], 'g', 'e', 'e', 'e', ['t', 'b'], 'b', 'b']
    '''

    in_group = False
    group = []
    result = []

    # Iterate through the pattern, character by character
    for c in pattern:
        if in_group:
            # If we're currently parsing a character
            # group, we either add a char into current group
            # or we end the group and go back to looking at 
            # normal characters
            if c == ']':
                in_group = False
                result.append(group)
                group = []
            else:
                group.append(c)
        elif c == '[':
            # A [ starts a character group
            in_group = True
        else:
            # Otherwise, we just handle normal characters
            result.append(c)

    return result

def check_if_matches(string, pattern):
    parsed_pattern = parse_pattern(pattern)

    # Useful thing to note: `string` and `parsed_pattern`
    # have the same number of elements once we parse the
    # `pattern`

    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(check_if_matches('betggeeetbb', 'bet[bge]geee[tb]bb'))
```